# UIToolbar style on iOS7

Tags: ios, styles, ios7, uitoolbar

I am trying to adapt my iOS to iOS7. I manage to fix most of the bugs but one that I don't understand is the barStyle of my UIToolbar which is not working anymore.

I used the following code:

```
UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height, 320, 44)] ;
toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
```

It worked fine on iOS 6 but on iOS 7 all I get is a grey bar and I cannot manage to change it. How can I fix this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
 toolBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```